# check EditText value onto ListView android

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

i am using ListView in main activity and class adapter extends ArrayAdapter  with login form only one row.

code adapter like this"

```
public class AdapterLogin extends ArrayAdapter<ListArrayItem> {

Context mContext;
int layoutResourceId;
ListArrayItem data[] = null;
  public AdapterLogin(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ListArrayItem[] data) {

    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.data = data;
}
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }
//here i have for login like this
  lin_form = new LinearLayout(mContext);
  EditText email_input = new EditText(mContext);  
  Button  btn_sign = new Button(mContext);
  btn_sign.setOnClickListener(login_btn_clicked);
  TextView login_status_message = new TextView(mContext);  
  lin_form.addView(email_input);
  lin_form.addView(btn_sign);
  lin_form.addView(login_status_message); 
  rowitem = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowitem);
  rowitem.addView(lin_form); 
  return convertView;

}


 public OnClickListener login_btn_clicked = new OnClickListener() {
 String email_value = email_input.getText().toString();
  // i want to see email_value but doesnt show me any thing
  login_status_message.setText("email value:"+ email_value);

};
```

in main activity i have a code like this:

```
    FillFooter fillfooter= new FillFooter();
    fillfooter.setFooter(MainActivity.this,"mainactivity");
    fillfooter.fillFooter();

 public static void gotoLogin(Context context){
        Activity activity = (Activity)context;
        activity.setTitle("Broonza: Вход"); 
        list = new HashMap<String, String>();
        listarraymain[0] = new ListArrayItem(1, list);
        AdapterLogin adapter = new AdapterLogin(context, R.layout.row_item, listarraymain);
        listviewtmain.clearFocus();
        listviewtmain.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

in the class fill footer

```
     public class FillFooter {
     public void setFooter(Context context,String typeactivity){
     this.context = context;    
     this.activity = (Activity) context;
     linaccount = new LinearLayout(context);
     linaccount.setOnClickListener(gotologin);
    }

    public OnClickListener gotologin= new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainActivity.gotoLogin(context);

    }
};
```

}
row_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="1dp" 
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:id="@+id/rowitem" >
```

load form login with all fields from adapter to listview  work fine, but when clicking button login if email field content text doesn't show that text.
The problem is not in the printed error!, The problem in the printing field email value! OnCLickListener() doesnt work. it will work only if i will add text for email_field onto inside adapter like this! email_input.setText("example@mail.ru")

Comment: Does the OnCLickListener() work, e.g. if you set a Log.i on click?

Comment: OnCLickListener() work only first click if field email empty. when you click button  login after loaded form login direct. if you print any thing onto email field to  OnCLickListener() stooped work

Comment: Do you want to see the email_value in your login_status_message?

Comment: no i dont see any thing! although the email field content text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all). after restart eclipse, it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of

```
if(error !=""){
   login_status_message.setText(error);
  }
```

should be this:

```
if(!error.equals(""){
  login_status_message.setText(error);
}
```

This is basically a string comparsion. If you want to compare a string to a string, you should use equals() instead of !=.

Comment: The problem is not in the printed error!, The problem in the printing field email value!  OnCLickListener()  doesnt work. it will work only if i will add text for email_field onto inside adapter like this! email_input.setText("example@mail.ru");

Comment: But you really should fix that string comparsion.

Comment: i am sure in that problem OnCLickListener() doesnt work. after printing any thing in EditText email.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the error value is always null and you can not see the value of email, it is not calling login_status_message.setText("email value:"+ email_value);
Change this

```
 btn_sign.setOnClickListener(login_btn_clicked);
 TextView login_status_message = new TextView(mContext);
```

by this:

```
 TextView login_status_message = new TextView(mContext);
 btn_sign.setOnClickListener(login_btn_clicked);
```

Comment: i change that and it is calling only this String email_value = email_input.getText().toString();        login_status_message.setText("email value:"+ email_value); but the same problem i cant see any thing even even "email value" doesn't show me

Comment: Are you adding your login_status_message to convertView? convertView.addView(login_status_message)

Comment: Post your row_item layout

Comment: yes i add that. if you click immediately btn sign after loaded form when email field empty to login_status_message will show  only "email value:" with empty value edit text email, but when you printing any thing in edit text email  to OnCLickListener() stopped work, and will not print anything even "email value:"

Comment: you can see know again my question  i add posted row_item.xml

Comment: i already  created text view login_status_message  before setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Your is initializing under the getView method and is local to that block;
How you are accessing this field outside the method?
You have created the object local with the method as-

```
   EditText email_input = new EditText(mContext); 
   TextView login_status_message = new TextView(mContext);
```

inside the getView method.
You need to put your Listener inside the getView method as

```
    btn_sign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    String email_value = email_input.getText().toString();
    // i want to see email_value but doesnt show me any thing
    login_status_message.setText("email value:"+ email_value);
    });
```

Re-examine the code if you are having another duplicate fields for that.

Comment: i I also tried this code. but No avail! you can see my code again. my be problem exists because i am using public static function to call adapter class and set adapter for list view inside static function ?